# react-native android-run failing (clean install)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

Here are my steps:

`react-native init app`

`cd app`

`react-native run-android`

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)`

`cd android && ./gradlew installDebug --info`

> Parsing /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/package.xml
>
> file or directory '/Users/xxxx/Projects/personal/app/android/app/libs', not found
>
> file or directory '/Users/xxxx/Projects/personal/app/android/app/libs', not found
>
> file or directory '/Users/xxxx/Projects/personal/app/android/app/libs', not found
>
> file or directory '/Users/xxxx/Projects/personal/app/android/app/libs', not found
>
> Using incremental javac compilation.
>
> Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

I do not know what the problem is here. Why is gradle looking for a lib that doesn't exist? Why is react-native not creating this directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this - for me it was because the SDK path was not working for some part of the process. I had 
`export ANDROID_HOME="~/Library/Android/sdk/"` 
which fails for this, whereas `export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/"` works fine.